# Qt C++ - Is there a way to display the same scale on high and low DPI?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

My laptop screen is on 125% and my monitor screen is on 150%. When developing a GUI I noticed that the window will look very different on the monitor from the laptop. Is there a way to make the GUI display on the same scale on both screens?

If not, is there a way I can scale the window size according to the DPI?

I tried three different ways as below but none of them work as what I want

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);
```

```
qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");
```

```
argc = 3;
argv[0] = (char*)"Appname";
argv[1] = (char*)"--platform";
argv[2] = (char*)"windows:dpiawareness = 1";
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on the same scale"?  Are you saying that, if you display a 100x100 pixel square, you want that square to be 100 pixels, regardless of scaling, even if that makes the squares be different size?